# Get Latitude and Longitude of a location

Tags: c#, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-geocoding-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how i can get latitude , longitude of a location programmatically or using a api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616582/how-i-can-get-latitude-longitude-of-a-location-programmatically-or-using-a-api)

I am using > http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXML.htm. to get the weather detials of location. Here I need to pass latitude and longitude to the webmethod. I have location name but not the latitude & longitude values.So I want to get these 2 values of a location. Is there any way to get it.

Comment: Could you give an example for a location name you're working with?

Comment: In that case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490622/get-latitude-and-longitude-based-on-location-name-google-maps-api) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246553/googles-geocode-convert-city-state-into-latitude-longitude) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with Google I presume you would want to use the [Google Geocoding API service](http://Google%20Geocoding%20API%20service)? The documenation there pretty much explains how to use it - you pass the address as a query-string parameter to the service (via simple REST like URL) and you can get back either XML or JSON. An example of an XML query:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

As part of the XML response you will see the lat/long:

```
<location>
  <lat>
     37.4213068
  </lat>
  <lng>
     -122.0852900
   </lng>
</location>
```

Just remember to set the `sensor` parameter to either `true` or `false` as this is required.

Note the v3 API doesn't require an API key but does have some [usage limitations](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) you should be aware of, including:

- a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day.
- the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited